# include part of ruby module hierarchy

Tags: ruby, namespaces

If I have a bunch classes that look like:

```
 module A
   module B
     module C
       module D
         class SpecificClass1
         end
       end
     end
   end
 end
```

And I don't want to refer to the class like

```
 instance = A::B::C::D::SpecificClass1.new
```

One way is to do:

```
include A::B::C::D
instance = SpecificClass1.new
```

What if I wanted to do something like this:

```
include A::B
instance = C::D::SpecificClass1.new
```

Why does this not work?  It returns:

```
uninitialized constant C::D (NameError)
```

Is there a way to effectively do what I'm attempting?

Comment: Cannot be reproduced.

Comment: BTW, you have a typo `instance = C::D::SpecifiClass1.new`. `SpecifiClass1` should be `SpecificClass1`

Comment: Hmm, my oversimplified example does work.  So I move around where I 'split' the module hierarchy and in some cases it works!  I have a hunch because another required file in this class has the same suffix so there is a name collision?

Comment: I've not seen this, and don't know if it's a good idea, but you could write `def specific_class1_instance; eval "A::B::C::D::SpecificClass1.new"; end` to enable (after adding `def m; puts 'hi'; end` to the class) `specific_class1_instance.m #=> hi`. I don't think you need to be concerned about the eval police here.

Comment: @CarySwoveland why `eval` at all since you have the appropriate module chain then `A::B::C::D::SpecificClass1.new` would work.

Comment: @engineersmnky, Initially, the class name was an argument so I needed `eval`. At the last minute I decided to remove the argument, but neglected to cast out `eval`. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

From irb session:

```
module A
  module B
    module C
      module D
        class SpecificClass1
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

=> nil 
2.1.0 :011 > A::B::C::D::SpecificClass1.new
=> #<A::B::C::D::SpecificClass1:0x0000010248f3c0> 
2.1.0 :012 > include A::B::C::D
=> Object 
2.1.0 :013 > instance = SpecificClass1.new
=> #<A::B::C::D::SpecificClass1:0x00000103803b40> 

2.1.0 :011 > include A::B
=> Object 
2.1.0 :012 > instance = C::D::SpecificClass1.new
=> #<A::B::C::D::SpecificClass1:0x0000010247b848>
```